# Use selectNodes with multiple alternative paths OR combine 2-3 IXMLDOMNODELIST

Tags: dom, vbscript, selectnodes

Just wondering if anyone would be able to help with the following VBScript script I'm writing:

Can I do somthing similar to this:

Set obj = something.selectNodes(path1, path2, path3)
// Where it will match either of the paths?

Or, if not, is there a way I can combine what selectNodes returns (IXMLDOMNodeList)? e.g.

Set obj1 = something.selectNodes(path1)
Set obj2 = something.selectNodes(path2)

Set obj3 = obj1 + obj2

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it was actually XPATH sytax I needed to learn about, specifically using XPATH like an SQL SELECT statement, e.g.

Set obj = something.selectNodes([(path1 and path2) or path3])